# ListView data not showing in Kotlin

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, kotlin

I am trying to display a custom list view having two string values side by side in a fragment under tab layout but data is not showing.

When I run the application nothing shows up just the blank screen.

I followed this guide : [javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/kotlin-android-custom-listview)

and tried to apply it to the fragment.

[image]

---

**CustomAdapter.kt**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.ViewParent
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.TextView

class CustomListAdapter(private val context: Activity, private val keyName: Array<String>, private val valueName: Array<String>) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.customer_list_view){
override fun getView(position: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View{
    val inflater = context.layoutInflater
    val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_list_view, null, true)

    val keyNameText = rowView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.keyName)
    val valueNameText = rowView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.valueName)

    keyNameText.text = keyName[position]
    valueNameText.text = valueName[position]

    return rowView
}
```

}

**FragmentSoftware.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ListView

class FragmentSoftware : Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val fragmentVar: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.software_fragment, container, false)

    val names = arrayOf("Tesla", "BMW", "Audi", "Tata", "Ford", "Honda", "Jaguar", "Mustang", "Mercedes", "Lamborghini", "Tesla", "BMW", "Audi", "Tata", "Ford", "Honda", "Jaguar", "Mustang", "Mercedes", "Lamborghini")
    val values = arrayOf("Tesla", "BMW", "Audi", "Tata", "Ford", "Honda", "Jaguar", "Mustang", "Mercedes", "Lamborghini", "Tesla", "BMW", "Audi", "Tata", "Ford", "Honda", "Jaguar", "Mustang", "Mercedes", "Lamborghini")


    val fragmentListView = fragmentVar.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView2)
    fragmentListView.adapter = CustomListAdapter(requireActivity(), names, values)

 return fragmentVar
}
```

}

**software_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_list_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/keyName"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/valueName"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can go with [RecyclerView](https://www.codingdemos.com/android-gridlayout-example-recyclerview) with GridLayoutManager

Comment: @MuthuS Yes, it's way better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you still need to override some method in your adapter and the most important one `getCount()`

```
//1
override fun getCount(): Int {
  return keyName.size
}

//2
override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
  return keyName[position]
}

//3
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
  return position.toLong()
}
```

Comment: what is dataSource here?

Comment: Thank you so much.  And in getItem function, Any was giving an error so I changed it to String and it worked as expected- is it correct?   And can you guide me through some info on how ArrayAdapter is working here, can any good resource also:D

Comment: check this great tuto here : https://www.raywenderlich.com/155-android-listview-tutorial-with-kotlin , it will explain you everything you need about listview , adapter ,....

Answer (score 1):

You may go with RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. you can increase span count you needed. [Clone this](https://github.com/MuthuHere/SimpleRecyclerViewKotlin.git)  :) Happie coding:)

Comment: Happy coding:) Best luck:)